# How to change the onclick value of the button if user select other option?

Tags: javascript, html, selection, onchange

Just new on javascript and I need to change the value of `onclick` on the button if the user selects the option 5.

I have this code:

```
function optionCheck(that) {
    if (that.value == "op2") {
        alert("Note: Thank You. Option 2!");
    } else if (that.value == "op5") {
        document.getElementById("oKay").onclick = "optionFive()";    
    } else {
        document.getElementById("keycheck").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="selections" onchange="optionCheck(this);">
    <option value="op1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="op2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="op3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="op4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="op5">Option 5</option>
</select>

<div class="col-lg-4">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="oKay" onclick="startOtherfunc()">Okay</button>
</div>
```

but my code seems not working.

Comment: Do you need to change the `<button value="">` of the button or the `innerHTML` of the button.

Answer (score 0):

assuming there is function called `optionFive`, you can set the `click` handler

```
function optionFive() {
     alert('optionFive function')
};
document.getElementById("oKay").onclick = optionFive;
```

Comment: I need to change the `startOtherfunc()` on the button if user select the Option 5 in the selections.

Comment: yea, thats what this does.

Comment: okay, but after I select the Option 5 I do not need to click the `Okay` button because the function automatically starts. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `.innerHTML` property? This will change the text inside the button. For example

```
function optionCheck(that) {
    if (that.value == "op2") {
        alert("Note: Thank You. Option 2!");
    }
    else if (that.value == "op5") {
        document.getElementById("oKay").innerHTML = "new text";    
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("keycheck").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Okay so I think this should work: I just used an event listener instead of `onClick`. I'm not sure why it works this way and not the other way if I'm honest.

```
function doSomethingElse(){
  console.log('Doing something else');
  return false;
}
function doSomething(){
  console.log('Doing something');
  return false;
}

function optionCheck(that) {
    if (that.value === "op2") {
        alert("Note: Thank You. Option 2!");
    }
    else if (that.value === "op4") {
        document.getElementById("oKay").addEventListener("click", doSomething);
        // document.getElementById("oKay").onClick = doSomething();    
    }
    else if (that.value === "op5") {
        // document.getElementById("oKay").onClick = doSomethingElse();  
        document.getElementById("oKay").addEventListener("click", doSomethingElse);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("keycheck").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: no I need to change the onclick value of the button if user click option 5